# How to recover my deleted history in terminal using #history -c

Tags: bash, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have cleared all my history in terminal using #history -c.
Now I want to recover all my commands which are cleared. please give me a reply

Answer (score 15):

#### I want to recover all my commands which are cleared

- `history -c` will clear `~/.bash_history` in **that** shell.
- `bash` does not immediately flush history to the `~/.bash_history`.
- `~/.bash_history` is not overwritten until you write the file using `history -w`.
- If you really want to clear the history you need to use `history -cw` in all open shells.

---

#### If you have **not** used `history -w`

- You can reload the history using `history -r`.
- If you log out and log in again your history will also be restored.

---

#### If you used `history -w` in one shell and you have other shells open

- You can save your history from that shell using `history -w` (although it will not be the same history as the other shell)

---

#### If you used `history -c` and `history -w` in every open shell

- your history is lost